# Let $G' \subset H < G$. Show that $H\unlhd G$ using the correspondance theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G' \subset H < G$. Show that  $H\unlhd G$ using the
>   correspondance theorem.

I already know that $G' \unlhd G$ and the natural application $v_{G'} : G \to G'/G$ is an epimorphism. From this fact and the correspondance theorem, we have  $v_{G'}(H) < G/G'$.

I am not able to go further. From what I have done, is that someone could give me a good hint to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correspondence theorem gives us a correspondence between the subgroups of $G/G'$ and the subgroups of $G$ which contain $G'$, but furthermore, **it maps normal subgroups to normal subgroups**

We know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $G'$, so by the Correspondence Theorem we know there is a subgroup (namely $H/G'$) of $G/G'$ which corresponds to H

Can you think of any properties of $G/G'$ which can tell us that this corresponding subgroup of $G/G'$ is normal in $G/G'$?

What does this tell us about H?

Comment: I see the fact $G'/G$ is abelian, but I really don't know how to finish it. Could you explain to me?

Comment: $G/G'$ abelian tells us that every subgroup of $G/G'$ is normal in $G/G'$
(look here if you can't see why that is: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Abelian_Group_is_Normal)

ie. The subgroup of $G/G'$ which corresponds to $H$ is normal in $G/G'$

Can you see why this tells us that $H$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: This is not clear at all that $H \unlhd G/G'$, because $H$ is subset of $G$ and $G/G'$ is a set of subsets of $G$. How could you explain that $H \subset G/G'$. You probably mean $\{H\} \subset G/G'$, isn't it? Furthermore, can you explain why $H \unlhd G$ by the above result? I'm a bit confused actually.

Comment: $H$ isn't normal in $G/G'$ because $H$ isn't a subgroup of $G/G'$. Our goal is to show that it is normal subgroup of $G$. We do this by showing that the subgroup of $G/G'$ which corresponds to H by the Correspondence Theorem is normal in $G/G'$ (remember the Correspondence theorem gives a correspondence between the subgroups of $G/G'$ and the subgroups of $G$ which contain $G'$). This tells us that $H$ is normal in $G$ because the Correspondence Theorem maps normal groups to normal groups. We know this subgroup of $G/G'$ which corresponds to $H$ is normal (in $G/G'$) because $G/G'$ is abelian.